# xcode 7.3 can not find glances in my watch

Tags: xcode, swift, apple-watch, xcode7.3, apple-watch-glances

I updated my Xcode to 7.3, and when I opened my watch apps, I found that my glances can not be show in apple watch, I opened My Watch on my iphone simulator and can not find "show glances" option anymore。。。I created an empty watch project(with glances) and still can not find 'glances' in My Watch

Anybody got idea? Thanks!

[Create a new watch project with glances](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ecQcF.png)

[Can not find glances](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LEAIR.png)